# How to verify that phone is connected to any cellular service provider?

Tags: android, automation, adb

I found how to call , but even when the device has no sim card it returns no error, so it doesn't help me:

```
adb -s <device number> shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:55678888
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the content of `telephony.registry` by using - `adb shell dumpsys telephony.registry` and then parse it. Look for the value of `mServiceState`:

> 0 - In Service
>    1 - Out of Service
>    2 - Emergency Only